# Table focus on view row jQuery / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I work on a project [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). I made a table in [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)which is a `partial view` and a form (`partial view` too) to output details.

When I select a row, his details are printed in the form but the view of my table leaves that of the selected row to return to beginning of the table.
Nothing that the selected row is still selected.

I tried `focus()` on selected row but not success.

Here is the answer of my controller:

```
public ActionResult GetTransactionById(int idTrans) {
        MP_TRANSACTION trans = db.MP_TRANSACTION.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == idTrans);
        if (trans != null)
        {
            TransactionViewModel mvm = initWithoutArrayTransaction();

            mvm._Transaction = new Transaction
            {
                    ID = trans.ID,
                SENDER = trans.SENDER,
                RECEIVER = trans.RECEIVER,
                BASE_CURRENCY = trans.BASE_CURRENCY,
                FINAL_CURRENCY = trans.FINAL_CURRENCY,
                AMOUNT = trans.AMOUNT,
                RATE = trans.RATE,
                CREATION_DATE = trans.CREATION_DATE
            };
            return PartialView("TransactionDetail", mvm);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { severity = "Important", message = "Error: Invalid Id Transaction" });
        }
    }

 private TransactionViewModel initWithoutArrayTransaction() {
        List<string> currency = (db.MP_CURRENCY.Select(s => s.CODE)).ToList<string>();     
        List<SelectListItem> codeList = TransformItemsInSelectListItem(currency);

        TransactionViewModel result = new TransactionViewModel
        {
            CurrencyList = new SelectList(codeList, "Value", "Text", ""),
            _Transaction = new Transaction { },
            ArrayTransaction = new List<MP_TRANSACTION>
            { }
        };
        return result;
    }
```

Here is part of code html with view:

```
<form id="formCash">
     @Html.Partial("TransactionDetail", Model)
</form>

<table id="cashTable">
     @Html.Partial("TableTransaction", Model)
</table>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cashTable tbody tr").on('click', function() {
    if ($('#cashTable tbody tr').hasClass('selectedRow')) {
      $('#cashTable tbody tr').removeClass('selectedRow');
    }
    $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
    //getTransactionById();
  });

});

/*function getTransactionById() {
$(tr).addClass('selectedRow');
$.ajax({
    url: "/.../GetTransactionById",
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        idTrans: idTrans
    }
}).done((data) => {
    $('#formCash').html(data);
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
});*/
```

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#cashTable thead {
  display: block;
}

#cashTable tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 5em;
  /* 5 times the equivalent of a text "size". */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#cashTable thead tr th:nth-child(1) {
  /* column 1 ! */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable thead tr th:nth-child(2) {
  /* column 2 */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable thead tr th:nth-child(3) {
  /* column 2 */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable thead tr th:nth-child(4) {
  /* column 2 */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(1) {
  /* column 1 ! */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) {
  /* column 2 */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(3) {
  /* column 2 */
  width: 120px;
}

#cashTable tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(4) {
  /* column 2 */
  width: 120px;
}

.selectedRow {
  background-color: #522D25 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

th {
  font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS";
  color: #F2EDEB;
  background: #522D25;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formCash">
  <label for="currencyBase">Base Currency</label>
  <input type="text" id="currency" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="amount">Amount</label>
  <input type="number" id="amount" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="rate">Exchange rate</label>
  <input type="number" id="rate" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="name">Sender</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="nameDest">Receiver</label>
  <input type="text" id="nameDest" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="currencyFinal">Final Currency</label>
  <input type="text" id="currency" />
  <br /><br />
  <label for="time">Date</label>
  <input type="date" id="time" />
  <br /><br />
</form>

<table id="cashTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sender</th>
      <th>Currency</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Exchange Rate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>JM Fillon</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>123.5</td>
      <td>4.0876</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>L OBAMA</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>205</td>
      <td>4.0376</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>V CAMERON</td>
      <td>EURO</td>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>3.0876</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C POUTINE</td>
      <td>XOF</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>4.3876</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>P TRUDEAU</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>4.0876</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M TRUMP</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>4.086</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M CLINTON</td>
      <td>CAD</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>4.076</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M MACRON</td>
      <td>EURO</td>
      <td>123.5</td>
      <td>4.087</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M BERLUSCONI</td>
      <td>USD</td>
      <td>123.5</td>
      <td>4.087</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M gtgtg</td>
      <td>CAD</td>
      <td>123.5</td>
      <td>4.876</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M gyyy</td>
      <td>XOF</td>
      <td>123.5</td>
      <td>4.876</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want if i select row of M BERLUSCONI, after printed details in form, my view table stay on row Berlusconi. But actually, it scrolls up to the top of the table.
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what this part means: "the view of my table leaves that of the selected row to return to beginning of the table." - do you mean it scrolls up to the top of the table?  It's most likely just selecting your form's first input which, if they are side-by-side will be at the top.  If you table is in a scrollable-div then you'll have some code to move it.  Without any of your code, it's impossible to tell what's causing the problem.  `focus()` is for input focus. Have a read of [ask], try to create an [mcve] to reproduce the issue in the *shortest amount of code possible* and paste here.

Comment: Yes that's it. When I select row  table scroll up to the top of the table. The view that is returned is partial. She does not change my table. I select the first row only when I refresh the table.

Comment: @AxelMadode Avoid to render again the `<table>`. What is the response of `/.../GetTransactionById` method?

Comment: I use `JSON` or `CSV` to render the necessary data in a view.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I updated code. Briefly, GetTransactionById return a partial View "TransactionDetail" that updates #formCash form

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez Yes I would have been able to make it as you say with the JSON but specially in my case I return many data. The update of fields in jQuery will be very long